# How do I fix the calculator error in my code?

Tags: javascript

Help me, please.  My javascript code is not working. I am trying to write a differentiated payment calculator. But my code doesn't work. It looks like the error is somewhere in the loop. I can not understand. The same python code works without problems.
My code:

````
function result_differ() {
     amount_of_credit = document.getElementById('amount_of_credit').value; 
     amount_of_credit = parseFloat(amount_of_credit);
     credit_term = document.getElementById('credit_term').value;
     credit_term = parseInt(credit_term);
     interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
     interest_rate= parseFloat(interest_rate);
     initial_fee = document.getElementById('initial_fee').value;
     initial_fee = parseFloat(initial_fee);
 
     part_of_the_principal = amount_of_credit / credit_term;
    
    if (initial_fee == 0) {
        let loan_payment_amount = [];
        let arr_range = range(1, credit_term + 1);
        for (let mes = 1; mes <= arr_range.lenght; mes++) {
            interest_amount = amount_of_credit * (interest_rate / 100) * 30 / 365;
            payment_amount_per_month = part_of_the_principal + interest_amount;
            loan_payment_amount.push(payment_amount_per_month);
            out.innerHTML = payment_amount_per_month.toFixed(2) + "<br />";
            amount_of_credit = amount_of_credit - part_of_the_principal;
        }
        document.getElementById('success_text_div').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            let loan_payment_amount = [];
            let arr_range = range(1, credit_term + 1);
            loan_amount_minus_installment = amount_of_credit - initial_fee;
            part_principal_minus_installment = loan_amount_minus_installment / credit_term;
            for (let mes = 1; mes <= arr_range.lenght; mes++) {
                interest_amount = loan_amount_minus_installment * (interest_rate / 100) * 30 / 365;
                payment_amount_per_month = part_principal_minus_installment + interest_amount;
                loan_payment_amount.push(payment_amount_per_month);
                out.innerHTML = payment_amount_per_month.toFixed(2) + "<br />";
                loan_amount_minus_installment = loan_amount_minus_installment - part_principal_minus_installment;
            }
            document.getElementById('success_text_div').style.display = 'block';
         }
     } ```
````

Comment: I think you missed pronounce this part `arr_range.lenght` should be `arr_range.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in the for-loop.
`for (let mes = 1; mes <= arr_range.lenght; mes++)`
It has to be:
`for (let mes = 1; mes <= arr_range.length; mes++)`

Comment: No problem. It would be nice if you mark the answer as accepted @avldokuchaev